# GCC assume aligned

Tags: c++, gcc

I have the following method:

```
void foo(float* __restrict a, float* __restrict b) {
    float* aAlign = __builtin_assume_aligned(a, 16);
    float* bAlign = __builtin_assume_aligned(b, 16);
    ........
}
```

I want to assume that a and b are already aligned. However I can't use gcc built-in function because I'm using GCC 4.4.1 and I can't upgrade. How can I implement something similar for an old compiler?

Comment: __builtin_unreachable was probably not there either, so it doesn't seem easy. Anyway, with this old version, you are likely missing out on most of the optimizations that take advantage of this information. I believe your time would be better spent fixing whatever is preventing you from upgrading.

Comment: I as far as I'm understand the `__builtin_assumed_aligned` is the way to say to compiler that it free to use SIMD instruction. Another way to achieve the same result is use SIMD instruction directly via builtins or inline asm.